# Politer form of expletive?

Tags: politeness, offensive-language

Which term is more appropriate to use?

"fucked" or "buggered"

Comment: I assume you heard the phrase "bug off"?

Comment: @sotondolphin: No, they probably heard something in BrE.

Comment: I grabbed it from a written chat between colleagues. One said: "My local machine is buggered!" Then I google the term "buggered" and thought it would be equal to "fucked". But was not really sure about the level of politeness in using that!

Comment: BTW what is the meaning of BrE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What idea are you trying to convey ?

If you're trying to say you've got a problem, "I'm fucked" might not be the best way to say it. If you're talking with friends, you can indeed go for:

> - **I'm fucked**
> - **I'm screwed** (which might be a bit less familiar than fucked, but still pretty vulgar)

But when you have to be more formal, you can use:

> - **I'm done for**
> - **I'm a goner**
> - **I'm in (deep/serious) trouble**

As usual, try to adapt to the persons listening to you in order to fit in !

I haven't read/heard **buggered** that often, but I'm pretty sure it falls into the first category.